# Proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n^2 +3n}{5-3n^2} = -\frac{2}{3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

I got a question to prove, using the formal definition of sequence limits, that the limit of the series $A(n) = \frac{2n^2 + 3n}{5-3n^2}$ is $-\frac{2}{3}$.

### Formal Definition of Series Limit

We call $x$ the limit of the sequence $a(n)$ if the following condition holds:

For each real number $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that, for every natural number $n>N$, we have $\lvert a(n) - x\rvert < \epsilon$.

I tried to crack this all day, but I can't get past the inequality.

Comment: Factor out by $n^2$.

Comment: I think you mean *sequence*, not *series*. A series is when you're adding them all together.

Comment: Solve it for the corresponding real function f: x ____> (2x^2+3n)/(5-3x^2)     using integration and differentiation.

Comment: Consider the limit of the quotient of polynomials in its full generality.

Comment: The numerator and denominator get arbitarily close in terms of ratio to 2n^2 and -3n^2 respectively. That is A(n) is approximated by (2n^2(1+e))/((-3n^2)(1-e))

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Divide both the nominator and numerator by $n^2$ and use the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\text{const}}{n^2} = 0$

---

For the formal proof, choose $N = \max\{\frac {1}{\epsilon}, 2\}$

$$\left | \frac{2n^2 - 3n}{5-3n^2} + \frac 23 \right | = \left | \frac{6n^2 - 9n + 10 - 6n^2}{15-9n^2}\right | = \left | \frac{9n-10}{9n^2-15}\right | = \left | \frac{1 - \frac{10}{9n}}{n - \frac{15}{9n}}\right | < \left | \frac{1}{n - \frac{15}{9n}}\right | < \left | \frac{1}{n - 1}\right | < \frac{1}{N} \le \epsilon$$

Comment: Since the definition has $n\gt N$, I think you can get away with choosing $N=\max\{{1\over\epsilon},1\}$.  That is, you only need $n\ge2$ for $n-{15\over9n}\gt n-1$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yeah, you're right, although sometimes the inequality isn't strict depending from an author to author.

Comment: True, some authors use $n\ge N$.  I was just going with what the OP said.

Comment: @BarryCipra Right. Anyway I guess that's going too much into details. After all we might not need the $1$ at the end. All we need is to define $N$ as the smallest integer greater than $\frac {1}{\epsilon}$. We're guaranteed $N \ge 1$.

Comment: You are quite right.  The take-home message for the OP, I hope, is that you need to choose $N$ large enough so that all of the final four inequalities in the display are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to solve a lot of such questions that go to $\infty$ is that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$$

So, here, try to put the largest terms in the denominator. This can be done by dividing both the numerator and denominator by $n^2$ to reduce the expression to $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2+\frac{3}{n}}{\frac{5}{n}-3}$$

Now, both the terms $\frac{3}{n}$ and $\frac{5}{n}$ are zero, as ${n\to\infty}$, so the expression just becomes $\frac{2}{-3}$

i.e. $\frac{-2}{3}$.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

$A(n) 
= \frac{2n^2 + 3n}{5-3n^2}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
A(n)+\frac23 
&= \frac{2n^2 + 3n}{5-3n^2}+\frac23\\
&= \frac{3(2n^2 + 3n)+2(5-3n^2)}{3(5-3n^2)}\\
&= \frac{6n^2 + 9n+10-6n^2}{3(5-3n^2)}\\
&= \frac{ 9n+10}{15-9n^2}\\
&= \frac{ 9/n+10/n^2}{15/n^2-9}\\
\text{so}\\
|A(n)+\frac23| 
&= \frac{ 9/n+10/n^2}{|9-15/n^2|}\\
&\le \frac{ 19/n}{|9-15/16|}
\qquad\text{for } n \ge 4\\
&\le \frac{ 19}{8n}
\qquad\text{for } n \ge 4\\
\end{array}
$

The rest should be easy.

Comment: how did -9n^2/n^2 become 3?

Comment: Thanks. 3x3=3 only in my brain, sometimes. Fixed. Upvoted.

Comment: also, by the second to last line, 15/n^2 becomes 15/16, is that a mistake?

Comment: No, because of $n \ge 4$.